# Handling "Other User Is Modifying This Record" in PHP+JS CMS

Tags: php, jquery

I've got a multi-user CMS/Database and would like to offer some kind of "User X is currently modifying this record" message in the event that two or more users are modifying this record.

I'm having trouble finding examples of this but have experienced it in latest versions of Wordpress.

Theoretically I imagine you could update the record table with a field like "currently_modifying" and populate that based on page load and unload but is there a better way?

This doesn't have to be absolutely bullet proof but I would like it to be worthwhile.  I'm guessing something like this would be appropriate for Angular which I'm not very familiar with but willing to learn.

I'm using jQuery and pretty familiar with it.  Any plugin suggestions?

My holdup is fear that Page Unload method may fail frequently as user sessions die.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep track of users modifying the page in real time you'll have to send periodic messages/requests to the server (network-intensive). One common way around this is to simply warn the user before saving a record that it has since been updated. This is easy, just keep a timestamp in the page which is last modified. When a user tries to save the file it queries the server for the current timestamp - if that differs from the one the page loaded, the file has been modified by someone else.

If you're building this CMS to work on LAN then the network overhead of periodic requests is less of a problem.